# Unable to clone a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM (VMware) that is a member of a domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-vsphere

Are you able to clone Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs that are members of a Windows domain and apply a customization specification?

I'm trying to clone a running Windows Server 2012 R2 VM via VMware. Brand new install of 2012 R2, no updates, no antivirus, member of a workgroup. VM is running and I'm able to clone the VM and apply a customization specification. No problem.

When I join the original VM to a domain and try to clone it it fails (attachment, on third reboot). VMware says I need to call Microsoft.

I'm able to clone a running 2008 R2 VM that is a member of a domain and apply a customization specification.

Comment: Have you changed the SID?

Comment: That's what the customization specification is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you know about SID and guest customization. To those that have no knowledge about it:

- [Security Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379571(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [What is a SID (Security ID)?](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/what-sid-security-id)

Since the guest customization is a vmware feature that just triggers the System Preparation tools(that are built into the operating system). You will have to open a ticket/support_issue on Microsoft so they will better advice you how to deal with a system with no sysprep.exe after domain join.

If you are using vCenter 5.0u1 or 5.1u0, i suggest you to take a look at [this kb](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2037366).

**Workaround**: Apply sysprep manually - [Instructions here](http://vloreblog.com/2014/10/30/manually-using-sysprep-in-windows-2012-vms-and-templates/).

Comment: Sysprep is already included in Server 2012.

Comment: I know it is included. It is just a matter of "its not working as expected". The problem looks like as if sysprep it isn´t included on Windows...

Comment: And it also seems that you didn´t take a look at the workaround i suggested...

Comment: Sure, I get that I can run this manually but this doesn't scale. VMware should come up with a fix or remove the option for customizing a vm that it can't customize. To open a ticket with Microsoft costs $499 just so they can tell me, "Call VMware."

Comment: They don't need to fix something that it isn't their fault if it's broken. To me does not seem to be a Vmware problem, as they can't control specific behavior of sysprep like this one (vm already on domain). Sure that this doesn't scale but, your organization should have calculated expenses with software licensing and support.